# Not able to access DynamoDB table

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am following this [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html) and have setup the DynamoDB table and permissions as described, but the app crashes saying:

> CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:UpdateItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:some_number:table/Books" (The table which I am trying to access is on us-west-2).

Please find below the code and the error:

Code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //DynamoDB calls go here
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider=new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(getApplicationContext(),"us-west-2:some_num", Regions.US_WEST_2);
        AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddbClient);
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setTitle("Great Expectations");
        book.setAuthor("Charles Dickens");
        book.setPrice(1299);
        book.setIsbn("12345678901");
        book.setHardCover(false);
        mapper.save(book);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(mapper), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);
mythread.start();
```

**Error**:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9530
Process: com.example.imb_bng_04.dynamodb, PID: 30264
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: User: arn:aws:sts::some_number:assumed-role/Cognito_sampleapp2Unauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:UpdateItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:some-number:table/Books (Service: AmazonDynamoDB;
Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: NMSNFJB24D6G3MO8RL6H624FA)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:712)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:388)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:199)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:4181)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.updateItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1582)
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.doUpdateItem(DynamoDBMapper.java:1173)
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$2.executeLowLevelRequest(DynamoDBMapper.java:873)
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.execute(DynamoDBMapper.java:1056)
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:904)
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:688)
at com.example.imb_bng_04.dynamodb.MainActivity$1$override.run(MainActivity.java:32)
at com.example.imb_bng_04.dynamodb.MainActivity$1$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
at com.example.imb_bng_04.dynamodb.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:0)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
01-27 18:10:16.004 1430-4135/? E/ActivityManager: Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 0x0
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Go to the console to "IAM" and create authentication for the credentials user you supply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably didn't create policy, on AWS, every action is forbidden unless someone defined otherwise.

Go to "IAM" (Change the URL to your region - https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1)

on the left menu click on "Policy" and then "Create policy" and select the "Create your own policy"

At the Policy name and description write what you want, and at the Policy document insert:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:table/YOUR_TABLE_NAME"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now go to users:
https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#/users/

Select the user you created the credentials for, click the "Permissions" tab and click "Add Permission" and then "Attach existing policies directly"

[image]

Select the policy you created and try again

Answer (score 2):

I followed the same tutorial and had the same problem. Finally, someone on AWS forum pointed out that the tutorial assumes you are in US-East1 region when making the AmazonDynamoDB client object.

I had to make the following adjustment to the tutorial code for it to work (adjust for your region):

```
            AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_1) // CRUCIAL
            .createClient(
                    AmazonDynamoDBClient.class,
                    credentialsProvider,
                    new ClientConfiguration()
            );
```